# Can we guarantee an interesting common factor by repeating any number twice?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Generalizing [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225989/why-a-3-digit-number-repeated-twice-is-always-divisible-by-13), is the number formed by repeating an arbitrary $n$ digit number exactly twice guaranteed to be divisible by at least one other interesting integer (i.e. a factor other than $1$ and $10^n+1$) for all $n$? If so, how does the distribution of interesting factors change as *n* approaches infinity?

**Update**: for $n=1$ and $n=2$ this is clearly not true. What about for $n>2$?

**Example:** given $n=4$ and the number $abcd$, then repeating twice gives $abcdabcd$, which is trivially divisible by $10^4+1=10001$, but more interestingly is divisible by 73 and 137.

Comment: Asked a follow-up question here about solving for n: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3226109/can-we-construct-a-multiple-of-any-number-by-repeating-another-arbitrary-number

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.  For $n<3$ the answer is no since both $11$ and $101$ are prime, so repeating a one or two digit number does not guarantee an interesting factor.  They are the only known primes of the form $10^n+1$, so as far as we know all other repeats will guarantee an interesting factor.  If $10^n+1$ is prime, $n$ must be a power of $2$, but there might be some large $10^{(2^k)}+1$ that is prime.

Comment: Are you saying that once you get past n=2 you *are* guaranteed an interesting factor?  It sounds like that, but from the "No" at the start of your answer I wasn't sure.

Comment: The no is for $11, 101$.  Otherwise it could be there are no more primes of this form, or there could be some.  I don't know how far this has been checked, but I am sure it is up to enormous numbers.

Comment: Okay thanks for clarifying.  I've suggested an edit that I think might help.  Feel free to reject or reword as desired.

Comment: I messed up my edit (should have said "n<3") but SE won't let me make a 1 character edit and I don't want to add characters just for the sake of it.

Comment: @bob:  Fixed.  Thanks

Comment: Likewise!  Thanks